# Actualizar campo de entidad a partir de una secuencia de base de datos

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto de Spring Boot con consultas hacia una base DB2. Tengo la siguiente entidad:

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "FILTRO_CUPONES_T_C", schema = "LIQUI")
public class CuponAux implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "CNU")
    @NotNull
    private Integer cnu;
```

Mi inquietud es que, cada vez que se llene un registro en la base de datos, necesito que el valor de cnu se cargue desde una secuencia, por lo que hice lo siguiente:

```
    @Entity
    @Data
    @Table(name = "FILTRO_CUPONES_T_C", schema = "LIQUI")
    public class CuponAux implements Serializable {
    
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "ID")
        private Integer id;
        @Column(name = "CNU")
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seqCopagosCnu")
        @SequenceGenerator(schema = "LIQUI", name = "seqCopagosCnu", sequenceName = "SEQ_COPAGOS_CNU", allocationSize = 1)
        @NotNull
        private Integer cnu;
```

Pero no consigo el resultado esperado. Al contrario, obtengo una excepción advirtiéndome que el cnu es null.

Consultas:

- ¿Se puede utilizar una secuencia de una base de datos para un atributo que no esté etiquetado con @Id?
- En el caso de que se pueda, ¿es correcta la forma en que lo hago?
- ¿Falta algo en el manejo de la secuencia?

Comment: Lastimosamente no es posible, la generación de secuencias es únicamente para los `IDs`, he visto algunos ejemplos de modificaciones para lograrlo pero no es algo normal de realizar en hibernate, lo que puedes hacer es crear una secuencia de la cual obtengas su valor manualmente y asignar el valor a campo `cnu`

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta @RobertoEMoran. Confirmado esto, llamo a la secuencia en mi repositorio y lleno el valor con ella.